# Mmenu js is giving error cannot setAttribute of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I have project where it is must to use Mmenu js which is js library. [Here is the link](https://mmenujs.com/)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   new Mmenu("#menu", {
      offCanvas: {
         position: "left",
      },
      theme: "light",
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/9.1.0/mmenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/9.1.0/mmenu.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/work">Our work</a></li>
            <li>
               <span>About us</span>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <span>The team</span>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="/about/team/management">Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/team/development">Development</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <span>Services</span>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="/services/design">Design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/services/development">Development</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/services/marketing">Marketing</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
```

Here is the code. It not working at all. What I see is just an error in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setAttribute')

Please help me out with this. I have even tried previous versions but still its not working. I am using Chrome 99.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue and made some changes in it. Hope that's how you wanted it to work.

**Working Code Snippet.**

```js
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   new Mmenu("#menu", {
      offCanvas: {
         position: "left",
      },
      theme: "light",
   });
});
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/9.1.0/mmenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/9.1.0/mmenu.js"></script>

    <!-- The page -->
    <div class="page">

      <div class="mh-head Sticky">

        <a href="#menu" class="mh-text">demo</a>
      </div>
 
    </div>

    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/work">Our work</a></li>
        <li>
          <span>About us</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
            <li>
              <span>The team</span>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="/about/team/management">Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/team/development">Development</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Services</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/services/design">Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/development">Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/marketing">Marketing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```